# Phonegap Build: "Failed to copy cordova.js"

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I am observing below behavior while creating an app using phonegap build for last few days. Please note it was working fine a month back.

1. Whenever I create a new zip file and upload it on Phonegap Build and, when I hydrate the App on my cell phone, I am getting error "Failed to copy cordova.js"
2. When I do a Retry, it still gives above error.
3. Then, when I kill the app and restart again, It says "Running the local version" and then all my code changes appear in the App.

So, here I am baffled, that despite of giving above error message, till now App is building fine and all code changes are getting reflected correctly.
But this error is still not going away.

I tried to search many forums, But they speak particularly about Cordova CLI or Phonegap, But not Phonegap Build.

Additional Information:

1. Device: Iphone 6s
2. OS: iOS 10.3.1
3. I have included cordova.js in my index.html using below line of code.

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
   ```

Comment: I am having this exact problem. Were you ever able to fix it?

Comment: I am having the same issue. It is now 2019... Anybody has a solution?

Answer (score 0):

That is strange!  Some suggestions:

- You are referencing "cordova.js" as a script tag, but you are **not including** an actual "cordova.js" file for it, correct?  Only the script tag should be present.
- What does the PhoneGap Build Log say?
- Post a question in the [PG Build specific Adobe community](https://forums.adobe.com/community/phonegap/build).  Issues with the service do happen occasionally, so it could be something on their side.